# Azure Mobile Services and WCF service

Tags: asp.net, wcf, azure

I am new in Azure technology. I am going to develop a new system and thought about Azure as a solution, but I have a question and thought maybe someone from the community will clarify to me next. 
As a clients I am going to have Android/iOS application and an ASP.net website to administrate the data and perform client actions. Talking about ASP.net it is clear to me, I saw several tutorials on how to publish it in Azure. My question is about mobile client.
On Microsoft web site from Azure Mobile Services section I understood that you create a mobile service, a database and a client(Android/iOS/...) and than create all logic to work with a database on a client side. But from my point of view when you are going to have several clients, like mobile and web, not to duplicate code to work with database, it will be better to have one more level of abstraction, a WCF service, to perform all actions with a database and only receive requests and send responses to the clients.
So my question is, will it be a good solution to have

different clients(mobile/web) -> a WCF service -> a database, or I am missing something in Azure "get started" tutorials?

Bwt, talking about users authentication I am going to use Auth0, cause it provides a possibility to have a custom + OAuth authentications.